# ES 6 + Syntactic Sugar For Referencing Specific Object In Array Based On Object Prop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Example:

```
const arr = [ { id: 0, title: 'A' }, { id: 1, title: 'B' } ];
```

If I want to only get the object that has `id: 1` I can do the following:

```
const B = arr.filter(i => i.id === 1)[0];
```

I was wondering if there's some ES6 =< syntax out there that neatens this up or perhaps abstracts the fact that you're filtering / looping over an array to look for the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a single item from an array with a condition in a predicate function, you can use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `Array.filter()`:

```js
const arr = [ { id: 0, title: 'A' }, { id: 1, title: 'B' } ];

const result = arr.find(({ id }) => id === 1);

console.log(result);
```